# detecting device and OS type using mobile detect js

Tags: javascript, mobile, browser-detection

I am trying to use a device and OS detection script and came across with this mobile detect js plugin. It seems pretty clean yet quite confusing.

[GITHUB LINK](https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js) and [DOC LINK](http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/doc/MobileDetect.html)

It seems the documentation is not thorough and I am finding a bit confusing on how to create special cases. For example, what I am trying to do is to find whether user is visiting website using mobile or tablet and after that check is done the next step is to find the OS of the device.

```
function deviceDetectionScript() {

    var md = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);

    if (md.mobile() && md.phone() && md.tablet()) {

        If(ios) {

            //do something

        }
        If(android) {

            //do something

        }
        If(windows) {

            //do something

        }
    } else {

        // do something else
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure the correct way to achieve this. Or is there any other way around to achieve the similar functionality without using this script?

Comment: You have to be more specific. Saying "something like this" and posting poorly written code won't cut it. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

> For example, what I am
>   trying to do is to find whether user is visiting website using mobile
>   or tables and after that check is done the next step is to find the OS
>   of the device.

Just FYI, tablet is considered mobile.

You have a couple options when it comes to doing what you want.

To check if user is on mobile use `md.mobile()`.

To determine if it is a tablet or phone use `md.phone()` and `md.tablet()`. This returns null or brand name.

Finally to check OS use `md.os()`(it will print name of OS) or you can use `md.is('iPhone')` which returns true or false.

Other available functions:

```
md.mobile()                   // 'Sony'
md.phone()                    // 'Sony'
md.tablet()                   // null
md.userAgent()                // 'Safari'
md.os()                       // 'AndroidOS'
md.is('iPhone')               // false
md.is('bot')                  // false
md.version('Webkit')          // 534.3
md.versionStr('Build')        // '4.1.A.0.562'
md.match('playstation|xbox')  // false
```