# How to use detect.js from Darcy Clarke to detect OS Version and Browser Version?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I want to detect the Browser + Version and the OS + Version.
On Google i have found this tutorial.

http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/browser-detection-javascript/

I downloaded the detect.js files and tried it on localhost but it don't work.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [detecting device and OS type using mobile detect js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951414/detecting-device-and-os-type-using-mobile-detect-js)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved!
Jquery wasn't added